# how to return triple (was "row") number in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Can I return the  triple number in SPARQL query?

For example, in Oracle database we can do this with `rownum` pseudo-column or `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

So how to query it in SPARQL from DBpedia, for example?

We can count triples by using `count(*)` or `count(?var_name)` function in SPARQL, but how to display an incremental number for each triple in SPARQL query?
Is it possible?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you basically want line-numbers in the output solution set (which may have any number of columns -- SPARQL results aren't limited to delivering triples)? So an extra column, which increments on each row in the result?  If that's not right, I think you'll need to show a mocked-up example of what you want, and maybe something of what you've tried...

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible because SPARQL is designed to query RDF graphs, and RDF graphs are not tables.  Hence there is no concept of a row - instead data is represented by subject, object, predicate triples representing a graph.

A SPARQL SELECT statement does return a result set that is basically a row for each query match, but that's different than representing the data in rows.

Comment: I mean triples with word "rows", anyway I updated the question, thanks.